# Creating user management system in Node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have a requirement for hierarchical user management system

where I have 3 hierarchies:

1. User
2. Manager
3. Admin

Now, Admin should be able to get a list as well as edit  registrations with role 'User' as well as those with role 'Manager'.

'Manger' should be able to get a list of of registrations with role 'Users' and should be able to edit them.

I had thought of proceeding like:

```
router.get('/:role',auth.isAuthenticated(),auth.hasRole('admin'),  users.findByRole);
```

where `hasRole` defines the minimum level of role required to access/edit the data.

However, I do not want a Manager to be able to get the List of admins or edit the list of admins.

It should have access to users list only.

[This links suggests using bitwise operators](http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/)but I am pretty confused with the idea of integrating this piece of code with backend i.e saving and retrieving data from mongo db . Can I please get some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this project: https://github.com/arthurkao/angular-drywall

This is good MEAN-stack based web app template with user management.